# Check how long it takes for conhost to print

Tags: c++, cout, large-data

I have an array of booleans each representing a number. I am printing each one that is `true` with a for loop: `for(unsigned long long l = 0; l<numt; l++) if(primes[l]) cout << l << endl;` `numt` is the size of the array and is equal to over 1000000. The console window takes 30 seconds to print out all the value, but a timer I put in my program says 37ms. How do I wait for all the values to finish printing on the screen in my program so I can include that in my time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I actually have not attempted a solution yet @HansPassant. I am asking how to wait for conhost to finish printing all its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
...

int main() {
    //init code

    double startTime = GetTickCount();

    //your loop

    double timeNeededinSec = (GetTickCount() - startTime) / 1000.0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in defense of ctime, cause it gives same result as with GetTickCount:

```
#include <ctime>    

int main()
{
   ...
   clock_t start = clock();
   ...
   clock_t end = clock();

   double timeNeededinSec = static_cast<double>(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   ...
}
```

Update:

And the one with **time()** but in this case we can lost some precision( ~1 sec) because result in seconds.

```
#include <ctime>    

int main()
{
   time_t start;
   time_t end;
   ...

   time(&start);
   ...
   time(&end);

   int timeNeededinSec = static_cast<int>(end-start);
}
```

Combining both of them in simple example will show you the difference in result. In my tests I saw difference only in value after dot.